# Отображение на хостинге

Tags: php, html, css

При открытии файла html не через хостинг все выглядит таким образом (изображение 1)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но на хостинге все выглядит следующим образом (изображение 2)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ua">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class = "content">
<main>
<div class= "back">
    <div class = "nadp">
        <a style="color:#fff" >Ukrainian Fashion Week 2018</a>
    </div>
    <div class = "allphoto">
            <div class = "photo">
                <ul>
                        <li> <img src ="images/news/ukr.jpg" alt = ""></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "page1">
        <div class = "news">
            <p style="color:#fff">Головна подію світу моди в Україні – Ukrainian Fashion Week стартує з 1 по 5 лютого 2019 року в Києві. Дизайнери представлять колекції сезону FW19-20.
</p>
            <p style="color:#fff">Основною локацією Тижня моди стане Мистецький Арсенал. Тому з нетерпінням чекаємо на кращі моменти шоу.</p>
</div>

        </div>
        </div>
</div>
        <div class = "nadp">
        <a >Victoria`s Secret Show 2018</a>
    </div>
    <div class = "allphoto">
            <div class = "photo">
                <ul>
                        <li> <img src ="images/news/vic.jpg" alt = ""></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "page1">
        <div class = "news1">
            <p >Victoria`s Secret Show кожного року збирає навколо себе не мало галасу, адже є найяскравішою подією світу моди. До шоу починають готуватися за 18 місяців, тобто одне шоу ще не пройшло, а вже планують наступне. Не дивно що до такої події також ретельно обираються моделі. 

</p>
            <p >Зіркою цьогорічного шоу в Нью-Йорці стала Ріта Ора, під пісні якої дівчата й дефілювали.
Легендарне Fantasy bra в цьому розі одягла Ельза Хоск.
</p>
<p >Легендарне Fantasy bra в цьому розі одягла Ельза Хоск.</p>
</div>
</div>

        </div>
        <div class = "nadp">
        <a >MTV Music Awards 2018</a>
    </div>
    <div class = "allphoto">
            <div class = "photo">
                <ul>
                        <li> <img src ="images/news/mtv.jpg" alt = ""></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "page1">
        <div class = "news1">
            <p >В Нью-Йорці відбулася одна з найважливіших премій світу музики, а саме MTV Music Awards 2018. Фанатів премії очікувала несподіванка, адже в цьому році відмовилися від ведучого, тому статуетки вручали: DJ Khaled, G-Easy, Міллі Боббі Браун, Backstreet Boys та багато інших.

</p>
</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
</body>

</div>
</html>
```

Код php

```
<html>
<?php include_once "header.php" ?>
<?php include_once "menu.php" ?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<?php include_once "news.html"?>

</html>
```

Код css

```
    .allphoto
{
    margin: 80px;
    padding-right: 400px;

}
.photo 
{
    margin: 50px;
    padding-right: 250px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.photo li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.photo li
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.photo img
{
    padding-left: 65px;

}

.back
{
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.8);
  padding: 20px;
}

.line
{
    margin: 70px;
    width: 900px; 
    padding-left: 100px;
}
.line2
{
    margin: 70px;
    width: 900px; 
    padding-left: 170px;
}

.page1
{
    padding-left:160px;

}
.news1
{
    background: rgb(26, 13, 0,0.2);
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    color: #060d13;
}
.page1-home
{
    background: rgb(26, 13, 0,0.2);
    color: #060d13;
}
```

Comment: Разложите все ресурсы(стили скрипты картинки) по тем папкам из которых вы их пытаетесь загрузить...

Answer (score -1):

php не будет запускаться вне хостинга если не установлен например виртуальный сервер типа Denwer.

Comment: Это несколько спорное утверждение. Все зависит от контекста. Есть же php cli

Comment: Вопрос не читали, картинки не смотрели?) проблема какраз при загрузке на хостинг, а не на локальной машине =) для уточнений есть комментарии.